# Using toggleClass in jQuery to shrink a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toggleclass

I have a div and I'm trying to shrink it when I click a button. And when I click it again, I want it back to the original size. I'm using toggleClass for this, but I did something wrong with my code, and I'm not sure where. Please take a look. Thanks.

```
//*********************************************************************
<style>

    div {
    border: 1px solid black;    
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;  
    }
    .shrink {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    }   

</style>

//*********************************************************************  

<button type = "button"> click me </button>
<div> Can you tell me a secret? </div>

//*********************************************************************

<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">   

$(document).ready($function {

$("button").click(function(){
    $("div").toggleClass("shrink");
});               

});

</script>
//*********************************************************************
```

Comment: Code looks good to me, check console for error

Comment: What is the incorrect behavior you are experiencing?

Comment: I think that your code works http://jsfiddle.net/zu1ts3jL/

Comment: Hi Jessica the issue was the `$function` that you were trying to pass as... please take a look of the my answer below. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of a typo.  You wrote "$function {" but you probably mean this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

The rest is fine.
Also, document ready can be expressed in a shorter form:

```
$(function() {
    ...
    ...
});
```

Maybe you just confused those two.  I did a few times too, back in my beginner days :)

Answer (score 0):

Here: the jQuery `ready` method takes an anonymous function as an argument... so te problem with your code was only to pass that function `function(){}`

**Here you can see the code in action:** http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/41wmck17/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("button").click(function(){
    $("div").toggleClass("shrink");
});               

});
```